# Object reference not set

Tags: c#, object

I have a Asp.net-C# Web app, with 4-5 associated projects all written in c#. I'm using .net 3.5.

My problem is, when I try running my application from the solution, it shows an error:

**"Error    17  Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**

When I build/rebuild the solution, it will be gone. When I click the error it takes me no where. And another interesting thing is, there is no location specified for the error.

Please help.

Comment: There is an option called `Debug` in VS. Guess you should try it out. This error happens because of `null` value to your object in use.

Comment: this is one of the most common errors in .NET, unless you provide some details, like stack trace, it would be almost impossible for anyone to help you

Comment: On line 17 in your source code you are trying to access an object which is not initialized.

Comment: **Sachin Shanbhag** I know what Debug is.. As I have clearly told in my post, that error goes when I Build/ReBuild. When I click the error it dose not lead me to a page or section in my code. [link](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/bKLpiuDTLTqtcW2Vu78wf_aryASSDovQNpUd5lwb0KM?feat=directlink). There are no other information to provide. Thats the issue.

Comment: **darin dimitrov**, the error code changes every time I receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that some object is null, and you try to call a method or access a property on it.

For example this code will give the same error message:

```
string myString = null;
int length = myString.Length;  //gives error since myString is null
```

If you can't find out where, and for some reason don't have any stack trace, try adding a try/catch block around the code you think is suspicious and see if the error is there or not.

Another solution is to just add a breakpoint, and go through your code line by line untill it explodes.

Without more details, that is the best advice I can give you.

Comment: **oyvind-knobloch-brathen**, Problem is not that I can't debug or get stack trace. As I told in My post, I'm getting this error when I build my solution. But that error points _no-where_. When I re-build, that error is gone. and I can simply run the application. I'm not getting this error every time I build..

Comment: Please check this image.. [link](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/bKLpiuDTLTqtcW2Vu78wf_aryASSDovQNpUd5lwb0KM?feat=directlink)

Comment: @Vipin - It seems other people also have had the same problem as you, without any clear way of resolving it. Take a look at this link and try the things they have suggested there. Hopefully, it will resolve your problem. http://bit.ly/eW3Gti

Comment: Thanks @oyvind knobloch brathen.. Its the problem I'm facing. seems like there is no specific solution. :( lemme try those suggestions..